# SQL - Row size issue in SQL Server 2012 but not in 2014 version onwards

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2012, sql-server-2014

I am facing an issue while altering a column datatype. This issue is related to maximum allowable table row size. I have gone through lot of posts around this and tried to understand the row size concept and related things. As I understand, RowOverflow issue is fixed post SQL 2005 for variable length datatypes. But I'm seeing discrepancy with SQL version 2012 and 2014 and also not able to calculate the required 8060 byte row size to exceed for my table, I am posting in this forum to understand the real reason behind it from experts.

So, I have one database..I restore same bak file on SQL Server version 2012 and 2014. I am altering one column of a table from bit to tinyint..I am able to do it on 2014 instance but on 2012 I get below error-

Alter table 'xyz' failed because the added fixed column might cause existing data to go beyond the maximum allowable table row size of 8060 bytes.

Below are some stats (which obviously applies for both the instance since same bak has been restored) which might aid you to tell me what might be reason-

1. Table doesn't have any row inserted.
2. One clustered index with primary key present.
3. No rowguidcol column defined.
4. There are no computed columns.
5. No foreign key.
6. Total columns are 282 by count.
7. Sum of fixed length datatype is 590 bytes.
8. Sum of variable length datatype ((n)varchar, (n)varbinary) is 62732.(Plz do not ask why so much :))
9. Wasted Space = 424 bytes
10. Sum of inrow length of dropped columns = 5033 bytes (I could not figure out what was datatype of these; also apart from this there are two columns with 8000 bytes which are dropped). Below query i triggered to get these details.

Query:

```
WITH T AS 
( 
    SELECT  ISNULL(LEFT(MAX(name), 30), 'Dropped') AS column_name,
            MAX(column_id) AS column_id,
            ISNULL(MAX(CASE WHEN column_id IS NOT NULL THEN max_inrow_length END), 
                   MAX(max_inrow_length)) AS max_inrow_length,
            leaf_offset,
            CASE WHEN leaf_offset < 0
                 THEN SUM(CASE WHEN column_id IS NULL THEN 2
                               ELSE 0
                          END)
                 ELSE MAX(max_inrow_length) 
                    - MAX(CASE WHEN column_id IS NULL THEN 0
                               ELSE max_inrow_length
                          END)
            END AS wasted_space
    FROM sys.system_internals_partition_columns pc 
    JOIN sys.partitions p ON p.partition_id = pc.partition_id
    LEFT JOIN sys.columns c ON column_id = partition_column_id
                           AND c.object_id = p.object_id
    WHERE p.object_id = OBJECT_ID('XYZ')
    GROUP BY leaf_offset
)

SELECT CASE WHEN GROUPING(column_name) = 0 
            THEN column_name
            ELSE 'Total'
        END AS column_name,
        column_id,
        max_inrow_length,
        leaf_offset,
        SUM(wasted_space) AS wasted_space
FROM T
GROUP BY ROLLUP (column_name,
                 column_id,
                 max_inrow_length,
                 leaf_offset)
ORDER BY GROUPING(column_name),
         CASE WHEN leaf_offset > 0 
              THEN leaf_offset
              ELSE 10000 - leaf_offset
         END
```

Another couple of observations are, I was able to add new column to the table (though there is warning), but alter statement on same was failing with the error mentioned above. I was able to alter the datatype when I ran ALTER INDEX ON _ REBUILD; command on 2012 instance.

So, I would like to understand what is calculation behind its failure, I was not able to sum up to 8060 bytes which causes overflow. If it somehow, then why only with 2012 version and not on 2014.

Table Definition-

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[XYZ](
    [ID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [ISFORANALYTICSUPDATE] [bit] NULL,
    col1 [nvarchar](60) NULL,
    col2 [nchar](25) NULL,
    col3 [nchar](5) NULL,
    col4 [nchar](10) NULL,
    col5 [nvarchar](35) NULL,
    col6 [nvarchar](25) NULL,
    col7 [nvarchar](40) NULL,
    col8 [nvarchar](25) NULL,
    col9 [nvarchar](25) NULL,
    col10 [nvarchar](50) NULL,
    col11 [nvarchar](25) NULL,
    col12 [nchar](3) NULL,
    col13 [float] NULL,
    col14 [nvarchar](15) NULL,
    col15 [float] NULL,
    col16 [nvarchar](15) NULL,
    col17 [money] NULL,
    col18 [float] NULL,
    col19 [float] NULL,
    col20 [nvarchar](15) NULL,
    col21 [money] NULL,
    col22 [datetime] NULL,
    col23 [datetime] NULL,
    col24 [datetime] NULL,
    col25 [int] NULL,
    col26 [datetime] NULL,
    col27 [datetime] NULL,
    col28 [nvarchar](15) NULL,
    col29 [nchar](20) NULL,
    col30 [nvarchar](20) NULL,
    col31 [datetime] NULL,
    col32 [int] NULL,
    col33 [nvarchar](25) NULL,
    col34 [nvarchar](20) NULL,
    col35 [datetime] NULL,
    col36 [nvarchar](25) NULL,
    col37 [nchar](12) NULL,
    col38 [int] NULL,
    col39 [nchar](3) NULL,
    col40 [nvarchar](15) NULL,
    col41 [nvarchar](15) NULL,
    col42 [nvarchar](50) NULL,
    col43 [datetime] NULL,
    col44 [nvarchar](25) NULL,
    col45 [nvarchar](16) NULL,
    col46 [nvarchar](25) NULL,
    col47 [nvarchar](25) NULL,
    col48 [nvarchar](30) NULL,
    col49 [nvarchar](30) NULL,
    col50 [nvarchar](30) NULL,
    col51 [nvarchar](30) NULL,
    col52 [nvarchar](30) NULL,
    col53 [nvarchar](254) NULL,
    col54 [nvarchar](50) NULL,
    col55 [nvarchar](30) NULL,
    col56 [datetime] NULL,
    col57 [nvarchar](30) NULL,
    col58 [nvarchar](30) NULL,
    col59 [nvarchar](30) NULL,
    col60 [nvarchar](50) NULL,
    col61 [nvarchar](50) NULL,
    col62 [nvarchar](50) NULL,
    col63 [nvarchar](50) NULL,
    col64 [nvarchar](50) NULL,
    col65 [nvarchar](30) NULL,
    col66 [nvarchar](30) NULL,
    col67 [nvarchar](20) NULL,
    col68 [nvarchar](20) NULL,
    col69 [nvarchar](20) NULL,
    col70 [nvarchar](20) NULL,
    col71 [nvarchar](20) NULL,
    col72 [nvarchar](20) NULL,
    col73 [nvarchar](20) NULL,
    col74 [nvarchar](30) NULL,
    col75 [tinyint] NULL,
    col76 [nvarchar](15) NULL,
    col77 [nvarchar](15) NULL,
    col78 [datetime] NULL,
    col79 [datetime] NULL,
    col80 [datetime] NULL,
    col81 [nchar](3) NULL,
    col82 [nchar](3) NULL,
    col83 [nchar](3) NULL,
    col84 [nchar](3) NULL,
    col85 [nchar](1) NULL,
    col86 [nvarchar](15) NULL,
    col87 [nvarchar](20) NULL,
    col88 [datetime] NULL,
    col89 [datetime] NULL,
    col90 [nchar](3) NULL,
    col91 [nvarchar](20) NULL,
    col92 [nvarchar](20) NULL,
    col93 [nvarchar](20) NULL,
    col94 [nvarchar](20) NULL,
    col95 [nvarchar](20) NULL,
    col96 [nchar](3) NULL,
    col97 [nvarchar](20) NULL,
    col98 [nvarchar](20) NULL,
    col99 [nvarchar](20) NULL,
    col100 [nvarchar](500) NULL,
    col101  [nvarchar](20) NULL,
    col102  [nvarchar](25) NULL,
    col103  [nchar](3) NULL,
    col104  [nchar](3) NULL,
    col105  [nchar](3) NULL,
    col106  [nvarchar](25) NULL,
    col107  [nvarchar](60) NULL,
    col108  [nvarchar](60) NULL,
    col109  [nvarchar](60) NULL,
    col110 [nvarchar](60) NULL,
    col111 [nvarchar](60) NULL,
    col112 [nvarchar](60) NULL,
    col113 [nvarchar](60) NULL,
    col114 [nvarchar](60) NULL,
    col115 [nvarchar](60) NULL,
    col116 [nvarchar](60) NULL,
    col117 [nvarchar](60) NULL,
    col118 [nvarchar](60) NULL,
    col119 [nvarchar](60) NULL,
    col120 [nvarchar](60) NULL,
    col121 [nvarchar](60) NULL,
    col122 [nvarchar](60) NULL,
    col123 [nvarchar](60) NULL,
    col124 [nvarchar](60) NULL,
    col125 [nvarchar](60) NULL,
    col126 [nvarchar](60) NULL,
    col127 [int] NULL,
    col128 [nvarchar](60) NULL,
    col129 [nvarchar](100) NULL,
    col130 [nvarchar](254) NULL,
    col131 [datetime] NULL,
    col132 [nvarchar](20) NULL,
    col133 [nvarchar](15) NULL,
    col134 [nvarchar](15) NULL,
    col135 [nvarchar](15) NULL,
    col136 [nvarchar](25) NULL,
    col137 [nvarchar](15) NULL,
    col138 [nvarchar](15) NULL,
    col139 [nvarchar](15) NULL,
    col140 [nvarchar](15) NULL,
    col141 [nvarchar](15) NULL,
    col142 [nvarchar](15) NULL,
    col143 [nchar](3) NULL,
    col144 [nchar](3) NULL,
    col145 [nchar](3) NULL,
    col146 [nvarchar](25) NULL,
    col147 [nvarchar](25) NULL,
    col148 [nvarchar](15) NULL,
    col149 [datetime] NULL,
    col150 [nchar](3) NULL,
    col151 [nvarchar](15) NULL,
    col152 [nvarchar](15) NULL,
    col153 [nvarchar](15) NULL,
    col154 [nvarchar](20) NULL,
    col155 [nvarchar](20) NULL,
    col156 [nvarchar](20) NULL,
    col157 [nvarchar](15) NULL,
    col158 [nvarchar](15) NULL,
    col159 [datetime] NULL,
    col160 [datetime] NULL,
    col161 [nchar](1) NULL,
    col162 [nvarchar](50) NULL,
    col163 [nvarchar](50) NULL,
    col164 [nvarchar](50) NULL,
    col165 [nvarchar](50) NULL,
    col166 [nvarchar](50) NULL,
    col167 [nvarchar](50) NULL,
    col168 [nvarchar](50) NULL,
    col169 [nvarchar](50) NULL,
    col170 [nvarchar](50) NULL,
    col171 [nvarchar](50) NULL,
    col172 [nvarchar](50) NULL,
    col173 [nvarchar](250) NULL,
    col174 [nvarchar](100) NULL,
    col175 [nvarchar](max) NULL,
    col176 [datetime] NULL,
    col177 [int] NULL,
    col178 [tinyint] NULL,
    col179 [nvarchar](max) NULL,
    col180 [nvarchar](5) NULL,
    col181 [int] NULL,
    col182 [nvarchar](30) NULL,
    col183 [nvarchar](20) NULL,
    col184 [nvarchar](40) NULL,
    col185 [nvarchar](25) NULL,
    col186 [nvarchar](10) NULL,
    col187 [nvarchar](254) NULL,
    col188 [nvarchar](25) NULL,
    col189 [tinyint] NULL,
    col190 [nvarchar](50) NULL,
    col191 [nvarchar](100) NULL,
    col192 [datetime] NULL,
    col193 [nvarchar](1) NULL,
    col194 [nvarchar](35) NULL,
    col195 [nvarchar](25) NULL,
    col196 [nvarchar](50) NULL,
    col197 [nvarchar](3) NULL,
    col198 [nvarchar](6) NULL,
    col199 [nvarchar](25) NULL,
    col200 [nvarchar](25) NULL,
    col201 [nvarchar](50) NULL,
    col202 [nvarchar](25) NULL,
    col203 [datetime] NULL,
    col204 [datetime] NULL,
    col205 [decimal](15, 8) NULL,
    col206 [nvarchar](4) NULL,
    col207 [datetime] NULL,
    col208 [tinyint] NULL,
    col209 [nvarchar](25) NULL,
    col210 [datetime] NULL,
    col211 [money] NULL,
    col212 [nvarchar](25) NULL,
    col213 [datetime] NULL,
    col214 [nvarchar](20) NULL,
    col215 [float] NULL,
    col216 [float] NULL,
    col217 [nvarchar](20) NULL,
    col218 [nvarchar](20) NULL,
    col219 [nvarchar](60) NULL,
    col220 [nvarchar](60) NULL,
    col221 [nvarchar](60) NULL,
    col222 [nvarchar](60) NULL,
    col223 [nvarchar](60) NULL,
    col224 [nvarchar](60) NULL,
    col225 [nvarchar](60) NULL,
    col226 [nvarchar](60) NULL,
    col227 [nvarchar](60) NULL,
    col228 [nvarchar](60) NULL,
    col229 [int] NULL,
    col230 [nchar](11) NULL,
    col231 [nchar](6) NULL, 
    col232 [nvarchar](500) NULL,
    col233 [nvarchar](500) NULL,
    col234 [nvarchar](500) NULL,
    col235 [nvarchar](500) NULL,
    col236 [nvarchar](500) NULL,
    col237 [nvarchar](500) NULL,
    col238 [nvarchar](500) NULL,
    col239 [nvarchar](500) NULL,
    col240 [nvarchar](500) NULL,
    col241 [nvarchar](500) NULL,
    col242 [nvarchar](500) NULL,
    col243 [nvarchar](500) NULL,
    col244 [nvarchar](500) NULL,
    col245 [nvarchar](500) NULL,
    col246 [nvarchar](500) NULL,
    col247 [nvarchar](500) NULL,
    col248 [nvarchar](500) NULL,
    col249 [nvarchar](500) NULL,
    col250 [nvarchar](500) NULL,
    col251 [nvarchar](500) NULL,
    col252 [nvarchar](500) NULL,
    col253 [nvarchar](500) NULL,
    col254 [nvarchar](500) NULL,
    col255 [nvarchar](500) NULL,
    col256 [nvarchar](500) NULL,
    col257 [nvarchar](500) NULL,
    col258 [nvarchar](500) NULL,
    col259 [nvarchar](500) NULL,
    col260 [nvarchar](500) NULL,
    col261 [nvarchar](500) NULL,
    col262 [nvarchar](500) NULL,
    col263 [nvarchar](500) NULL,
    col264 [nvarchar](500) NULL,
    col265 [nvarchar](500) NULL,
    col266 [nvarchar](500) NULL,
    col267 [nvarchar](500) NULL,
    col268 [nvarchar](500) NULL,
    col269 [nvarchar](500) NULL,
    col270 [nvarchar](500) NULL,
    col271 [nvarchar](500) NULL,
    col272 [nvarchar](500) NULL,
    col273 [nvarchar](500) NULL,
    col274 [nvarchar](500) NULL,
    col275 [nvarchar](500) NULL,
    col276 [nvarchar](500) NULL,
    col277 [nvarchar](500) NULL,
    col278 [nvarchar](500) NULL,
    col279 [nvarchar](500) NULL,
    col280 [nvarchar](500) NULL,    
 CONSTRAINT [PK_XYZ] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [ID] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY] TEXTIMAGE_ON [PRIMARY]

GO
```

Command i am using to alter:

```
alter table XYZ alter column isforanalyticsupdate tinyint
```

Comment: Can you paste table definition ,along with column definition you are trying to add

Comment: @TheGameiswar You mean all 282 columns datatype and length ? The one which I'm altering is bit column and trying to make it tinyint column...

Comment: I can give further info like 
1. There are 281 Nullable columns
2. SUM([size of fixed length deep type columns]) = 272
3. SUM([computed size of variable length deep type columns]) = 62732
4. SUM([size of shallow types]) = 318

Comment: total table defintiion and  statement you are trying to add

Comment: @TheGameiswar Below is command I'm trying which throws error-

alter table XYZ alter column isforanalyticsupdate tinyint
...............
Table definition I have added in question as size is more to fit in the comment..

Comment: see this :http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/74198/apparantly-errorneous-exceeds-8k-row-length-message

Comment: @TheGameiswar Thanks for the link...Yes, I have gone through that earlier..I am also able to alter column after rebuilding index..but my que here is why rebuild is required only for SQL Server 2012 Standard (11.0.6020.0) and not for SQL server 2014? What is change introduced which handles it in 2014 (I went through features of 2014, but couldn't find relevant one)..if you can help me there...

Comment: i will test once i have 2014 server and will update if possible